# Fatal error: Class 'CModelEvent' not found in CModel.php on line 189

Tags: php, yii

I get this error(Fatal error: Class 'CModelEvent' not found) whenever I try to save model without using a post form but directly get data from an excel file and assign it to model attributes as given below:

```
   public function actionImportFile() {
        if (isset($_POST['User'])) {
            Yii::import('application.extensions.yii-phpexcel.PHPExcel', true);
            $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES['User']['tmp_name']['import_file']); 
            $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
            $model = new User('create');
            $model->firstname = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, 2)->getValue();
            $model->lastname = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, 2)->getValue();
            $model->password = 'password';
            $model->email = 'nt@yahoo.com';
            $model->usertype = -1;
            $model->status = 1;
            if ($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('index'));
        }
    }
```

Rules are defined as given below:

```
  public function rules() {
        return array(
            array('firstname, lastname, email, status, usertype, password', 'required'),
        );
    }
```

I think this error is due to validation fails because when I try to save model as `$model->save(false)` then It saves the record but i want to apply the validation rules.
Please help me if anybody knows about this error.....

I found one other thing if I cahnges my above function as given below:

```
public function actionImportFile() {
            if (isset($_POST['User'])) {
               // Yii::import('application.extensions.yii-phpexcel.PHPExcel', true);
               // $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES['User'] ['tmp_name'['import_file']); 
              //  $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
                $model = new User('create');
                $model->firstname = 'test'; //$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, 2)->getValue();
                $model->lastname = 'test2';//$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, 2)->getValue();
                $model->password = 'password';
                $model->email = 'nt@yahoo.com';
                $model->usertype = -1;
                $model->status = 1;
                if ($model->save())
                    $this->redirect(array('index'));
            }
        }
```

Then it saves the model but with uploading `$_FILES['User'] ['tmp_name'['import_file']` this it gives error.

Comment: try to print the error after save with validation: `$model->save(); print_r($model->getErrors());`

Comment: I already did so but the same result, Now tried it agion but the same error.

Comment: try: `$model->save(); print_r($model->getErrors()); die;` because the redirection not print the error

Comment: Thanks for you reply but still the same error.

Comment: I have updated my question to see the actual problem but not solved yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding `spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase', 'autoload'));` before import function `Yii::import('application.extensions.yii-phpexcel.PHPExcel', true);` and `spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase', 'autoload'));` after it. The whole function looks like below now and works fine now:

```
 public function actionImportFile() {
        if (isset($_POST['User'])) {
            spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase', 'autoload'));
            Yii::import('application.extensions.yii-phpexcel.PHPExcel', true);
            spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase', 'autoload'));
            $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES['User']['tmp_name']['import_file']); 
            $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
            $model = new User('create');
            $model->firstname = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, 2)->getValue();
            $model->lastname = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, 2)->getValue();
            $model->password = 'password';
            $model->email = 'nt@yahoo.com';
            $model->usertype = -1;
            $model->status = 1;
            if ($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('index'));
        }
    }
```