# Class not found error on new instance creation of a model even though required model class exists

Tags: yii

I have model:

```
class UserDetail extends CActiveRecord
{
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'user_detail';
    }
}
```

When I do this:

```
$userdetail = new UserDetail();
```

I get error:
 Fatal error: Class 'UserDetail' not found, Please if anybody can help me regarding this.
I have problem in action which is given below:

```
public function actionImportFile() {
        if (isset($_POST['ImportFile'])) {
            Yii::import('application.extensions.yii-phpexcel.PHPExcel', true);
            $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES['ImportFile']['tmp_name']['import_file']);
            $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
            $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
            for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
                $model = new User('create');
                $model->firstname = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();
                $model->lastname = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue();
                $model->email = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getValue();
                $model->password = UserIdentity::encrypt($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getValue());
                $model->usertype = User:: getUserTypeCode($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $row)->getValue());
                $model->status = User:: getStatusCode($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, $row)->getValue());
                $model->gender = User:: getGenderCode($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $row)->getValue());
                $model->current_grade = User::getGradeCode($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(9, $row)->getValue());
                $model->createTime = time();
                if ($model->save(false)) {


                }
                $userdetail = new UserDetail();
                $userdetail->user_id = $model->id;
                $userdetail->birthday = strtotime($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(8, $row)->getValue());
                $userdetail->zip = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(10, $row)->getValue();
                if ($userdetail->save(false)) {

                }
            }
        }
        $this->redirect(array('/admin/user/index'));
    }
```

Now when I change the above function as given below then it works fine but note that I have hard coded some lines which I need to dynamic.

```
 public function actionImportFile() {

        if (isset($_POST['ImportFile'])) {
            //Yii::import('application.extensions.yii-phpexcel.PHPExcel', true);
           // $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES['ImportFile']['tmp_name']['import_file']);
           // $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
            $highestRow = 2;//$objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
            for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
                $model = new User('create');
                $model->firstname ='test'; //$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();
                $model->lastname ='test';  //$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue();
                $model->email = 'test@abc.com'; //$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getValue();
                $model->password = 'test';  //UserIdentity::encrypt($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getValue());
                $model->usertype = 1;//User:: getUserTypeCode($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $row)->getValue());
                $model->status = 1;//User:: getStatusCode($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, $row)->getValue());
                $model->gender = 1;//User:: getGenderCode($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $row)->getValue());
                $model->current_grade = 1;//User::getGradeCode($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(9, $row)->getValue());
                $model->createTime = time();
                if ($model->save(false)) {

                }
                $userdetail = new UserDetail();
                $userdetail->user_id = $model->id;
                $userdetail->birthday = '';//strtotime($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(8, $row)->getValue());
                $userdetail->zip = 25000;//$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(10, $row)->getValue();
                if ($userdetail->save(false)) {

                }
            }
        }
        $this->redirect(array('/admin/user/index'));
    }
```

Comment: Where is your UserDetail model saved? Have you imported this folder? Note that imports are not recursive. If you have sub folders in your model folder for example, you must import every single sub folder in your config.

Comment: In another function of same controller the same line of code (`$userdetail = new UserDetail();`) works fine but not in this current function.

Comment: That's odd. Can you please show us the relevant controller code of these two methods?

Comment: I have updated my question please have look at actionImportFile and let me know whats wrong with this code 
`Yii::import('application.extensions.yii-phpexcel.PHPExcel', true);
 $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES['ImportFile']['tmp_name']['import_file]);
 $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();`

Comment: Same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699573/fatal-error-class-cmodelevent-not-found-in-cmodel-php-on-line-189

Comment: So with the first one you get the error of class not found but with the second (commented out) it works fine? Very strange, seems it has to do with the import. Can you please try to add `new UserDetail();` right before the line with the import and see if this works.

Comment: Yes with second(commented out) works fine. Yes before import it works fine.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Can you please try with a false instead of a true in this import. And remove the `new UserDetail();` beforehand.

Comment: Now I get error:
`include(PHPExcel_IOFactory.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: Try `Yii::import('application.extensions.yii-phpexcel.*');`
If that doesn't help I'm out of ideas.

Comment: It doesn't work too, anyway thanks for you ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding `spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase', 'autoload'));` before import function `Yii::import('application.extensions.yii-phpexcel.PHPExcel', true);` and  `spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase', 'autoload'));` after it. The whole function looks like below now and works fine now:

```
public function actionImportFile() {
        if (isset($_POST['ImportFile'])) {
            spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase', 'autoload'));
            Yii::import('application.extensions.yii-phpexcel.PHPExcel', true);
            spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase', 'autoload'));
            $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES['ImportFile']['tmp_name']['import_file']);
            $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
            $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
            for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
                $model = new User('create');
                $model->firstname = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();
                $model->lastname = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue();
                $model->email = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getValue();
                $model->password = UserIdentity::encrypt($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getValue());
                $model->usertype = User:: getUserTypeCode($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $row)->getValue());
                $model->status = User:: getStatusCode($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, $row)->getValue());
                $model->gender = User:: getGenderCode($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $row)->getValue());
                $model->current_grade = User::getGradeCode($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(9, $row)->getValue());
                $model->createTime = time();
                if ($model->save(false)) {


                }
                $userdetail = new UserDetail();
                $userdetail->user_id = $model->id;
                $userdetail->birthday = strtotime($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(8, $row)->getValue());
                $userdetail->zip = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(10, $row)->getValue();
                if ($userdetail->save(false)) {

                }
            }
        }
        $this->redirect(array('/admin/user/index'));
    }
```